# "Принимать за чистую монету"

Tags: фразеология

Есть такое выражение "Принимать за чистую монету" - так говорят, когда имеют в виду, что человек верит лжи, принимает какую-то подделку за настоящее. Интересно было бы узнать, откуда пошло выражение.
И раз уж тут принято высказывать для начала свое предположение, предложу свой вариант: имеется в виду чистота золота или серебра в монете или вообще подделка золота с помощью другого металла. Я прав?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы правы, здесь речь идет о подделке.

«Чистая монета» - монета государственной чеканки с определенным, строго установленным в ней содержанием благородных металлов. Фальшивомонетчики, жулики занимались подделкой этих монет и надували доверчивых простаков".

И в результате получается, как у И. Гончарова: "Он ...принимал за чистую монету всякий её взгляд, всякое слово".

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/10719559

Answer (score 2):

Нет, тут эпитет "чистая" отношение к пробе (чистоте) драгоценных металов имеет лишь косвенное. Под "чистотой" тут аналогично выражениям "чистые руки", "от чистого сердца", "чистая правда" и пр. имеются в виду *правильность, неподдельность*. Не чистой будет не только монета, где один металл заменен на другой, но и "недовесок", более легкая монета.

Чистая, не фальшивая монета, здесь выступает как измеритель цены поступков или слов. Думал, что искренне добро творят, а оказалось себе выгоду ищут. Выдают мусор за истинную ценность.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю лишь, что металлы во времена Российской Империи (насколько мне известно именно с тех времён и пошёл данный фразеологизм) добывались не так массово (читайте легко и продуктивно), как сейчас, поэтому жуликами-проходимцами зачастую добавлялись "неблагородные фракции" (подробнее можете почитать в соотв. статьях интернета, благо их в достатке), дабы снизить себестоимость и получить личную выгоду от фальшивомонетничества.